# ¿inner join en multiples tablas?

Tags: sql, oracle

mi consulta:

```
SELECT   *
FROM c INNER JOIN pro
        ON c.id = pro.nom_pro
     INNER JOIN s 
        ON s.descripcion = ...
```

Con este ejemplo que estoy trabajando se me van a aclarar muchas dudas acerca del innerjoin. Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aquí te muestro como hacer un `INNER JOIN` entre las 3 tablas de tu escenario

```
SELECT cursos.id AS IdCurso, cursos.nomb_curso, 
       profesores.id AS IdProfesor, 
       profesores.nomb_profe,
       aulas.id AS IdAula, aulas.descripcion
FROM aulas
INNER JOIN cursos ON aulas.id = cursos.id_aula
INNER JOIN profesores ON profesores.id = cursos.id_profesor
ORDER BY IdCurso;
```

**Consideraciones**

- La relación entre tus tablas es de muchos a muchos, pues tienes una tabla pivote llamada cursos, que contiene los `id` o llaves primarias de las otras dos.
- Para hacer la selección debes indicar por la sintaxis de `tabla.columna` para evitar ambigüedades en los nombres de las columnas
- Necesitas 2 `INNER JOIN` uno de cursos con aulas y otro de profesores con cursos.
- En los 2 `INNER JOIN` igualas a la llave primaria con su equivalente de llave foránea de la tabla pivote.
- Como te mencioné en los comentarios, tienes un error al crear la llave foránea, pues la sintaxis que deberías tener es:

Código

```
foreign key (llave foránea) references profesores(llave primaria),
```

Y tu tenías esta sintaxis

```
foreign key (llave foránea) references profesores(llave foránea),
```

> Dado que es algo extenso el código, te arme un ejemplo que te dejo en el enlace siguiente

[Ejemplo funcional en sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=716ed983809060954d4273d02502ef47)

Comment: me parece esa pregunta, sale del alcance de esta, pero puedes abrir una nueva que se guie por las mismas reglas que ya te comenté y esperar el apoyo de alguien que conozca de dicha herramienta @Innuendo

Comment: después del último `INNER JOIN` tu código debería quedar así `WHERE cursos.id = '1'
ORDER BY cursos.id;` es decir ocupas una condición `WHERE` para filtrar donde el id del curso sea 1 por ejemplo @Innuendo

Answer (score 2):

Te voy a dejar un ejemplo para hacer un inner join entre dos tablas. Si lo comprendes, fácilmente podrás ampliarlo a las 3 tablas que te interesan.

```
select   cursos.id as idCurso
       , cursos.nomb_curso as nombCurso
       , profesores.id as idProfesor
       , profesores.nomb_profe as nombreProfe
  from cursos 
       inner join profesores on profesores.id = cursos.id_profesor
```

Dado que los nombres de las columnas de tu estructura no coinciden con los nombres de las columnas que deseas obtener, he utilizado alias en las columnas, pero te advierto que no es la mejor práctica.

También he asumido que los nombres de las columnas son correctos, aunque el *script* publicado evidentemente no es el que has utilizado para crear tu estructura, pues tiene algunos errores. Si los nombres de las columnas difieren, realiza tu los ajustes necesarios. Lo importante es que comprendas la idea.

Es mejor que utilices un estándar de nombres a lo largo de todo tu sistema, eso evitará confusiones y en general, mejora la mantenibilidad de sistemas grandes.

Ahora, sobre ejecutar esta consulta desde java, no hay ninguna diferencia con ejecutar una consulta que va a una sola tabla.